# Issue With MediaFocusControl on Android App running API24 Nougat

Tags: android, audio

I am writing an app that sends audio through the USB output perfectly on all android versions up to Marshmallow, however on Nougat(API24) audio playback will start but then moments later the audio focus will go and the audio stutters and the app will then crash. Higher bitrate files play for longer before crashing but normal 44.1 files will only play for 15 seconds tops before the focus goes. I would be REALLY gratful for any help with this.

This is the logcat

```
11-01 15:06:46.624  4950  6816 I MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from uid/pid 10380/21138 clientId=android.media.AudioManager$6f5e0f7com.android.app.Core$7463b64 req=1 flags=0x0: system_server
11-01 15:06:46.624 21138 21245 D AudioManager: requestAudioFocus status : 1: com.android.app
11-01 15:06:46.626  4950  7001 I MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from uid/pid 10380/21138 clientId=android.media.AudioManager$6f5e0f7com.android.app.Core$7463b64 req=1 flags=0x0: system_server
11-01 15:06:46.627 21138 21245 D AudioManager: requestAudioFocus status : 1: com.android.app
11-01 15:06:46.635  4950  5524 D MediaSessionRecord: setPlaybackState oldState:1, newState:0, packageName:com.android.app: system_server
11-01 15:06:46.636  4950  5283 D MediaSessionRecord: setPlaybackState oldState:0, newState:3, packageName:com.android.app: system_server
11-01 15:06:46.637  4950  6533 D MediaSessionRecord: setPlaybackState oldState:3, newState:3, packageName:com.android.app: system_server
11-01 15:06:46.643  4950  6234 D MediaSessionRecord: setPlaybackState oldState:3, newState:1, packageName:com.android.app: system_server
11-01 15:06:46.644  4950  6851 D MediaSessionRecord: setPlaybackState oldState:1, newState:3, packageName:com.android.app: system_server
11-01 15:06:46.652  5478  5558 D vol.MediaSessions: onPlaybackStateChanged com.android.app STATE_PLAYING PlaybackState {state=3, position=-1, buffered position=0, speed=1.0, updated=231995683, actions=51, custom actions=[], active item id=-1, error=null}: com.android.systemui
11-01 15:06:46.652  5478  5558 D vol.MediaSessions: updateRemoteControllerH null: com.android.systemui
11-01 15:06:46.653  5478  5558 D vol.MediaSessions: onActiveSessionsUpdatedH n=2: com.android.systemui
```

Comment: Please add some code so we can see what you've done

Comment: Annoyingly this library is closed source :-(

Comment: I am using this which seems not to be working now on nougat API 24

Comment: try {
            int deviceType = DEVICE_OUT_USB_DEVICE;
            // turn off headset

            Class<?> cl = Class.forName("android.media.AudioManager");
            Method method;
            method = cl.getMethod("setWiredDeviceConnectionState", new Class[]{Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, String.class, String.class});
            method.invoke(mAudioManager, new Object[]{deviceType, state, "device", ""});